# Integral involving $\phi$

Tags: integration

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arctan\left({2\over \cos^2{x}}\right)\mathrm dx=\pi\arctan\left({1\over \sqrt{\phi}}\right)\tag1$$

$\phi$ is the golden ratio

$2\sec^2{x}=2\tan^2{x}+2$

$u=\sec^2{x}$ then $\mathrm du=2{\tan{x}\over \cos^2{x}}\mathrm dx$

$$\int{\cos^2{x}\over \tan{x}}\arctan\left({2\over u}\right)\mathrm du\tag2$$

$$\int{1\over u\sqrt{u-1}}\arctan\left({2\over u}\right)\mathrm du\tag3$$

Not so sure what is next step...

> How do we show that $(1)=\pi\arctan\left({1\over \sqrt{\phi}}\right)$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\arctan (2u)$?

Comment: We should have a $\frac12$ as well after substitution.

Comment: Numerically, r.h.s of (1) seems to be $\pi \arctan (\sqrt \phi )$.

Comment: @Paul Enta: (1) seems plausible numerically when entered in on my calculator

Comment: @James Arathoon You are right, I made a mistake.

Comment: After the substitution the definite integral becomes $\int_1^\infty{1\over 2u\sqrt{u-1}}\arctan\left({2u}\right)\mathrm du$

Comment: hint: your integrand equals $\Im[\log(2 i +\cos^2(x))]$ and $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(1+ a \cos^2(x))=\pi\log((\sqrt{a+1}+1)/2)$ as proven dozens of times on this site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arctan\left(\frac{2}{\cos^2\theta}\right)\,d\theta&=&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arctan\left(\frac{2}{\sin^2\theta}\right)\,d\theta\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan\frac{2}{u^2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\frac{u^2}{2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du\\&=&\frac{\pi^2}{4}-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)\,2^{2n+1}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{4n+2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du\\&=&\frac{\pi^2}{4}-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\pi(-1)^n (4n+1)}{(2n+1)^22^{6n+3}}\binom{4n}{2n}\end{eqnarray*}\tag{A}$$
The last hypergeometric series can be computed from
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2}\binom{2n}{n}z^n =\frac{\log 2-\log\left(1+\sqrt{1-4z}\right)}{z}\tag{B} $$
leading to
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{4n+1}{(2n+1)^2}\binom{4n}{2n}z^n =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}\,\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{z}}}{1+\sqrt{1-4\sqrt{z}}}\right) \tag{C}$$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^n\,\Gamma\left(2n+\tfrac{3}{2}\right)}{(2n+1)\,\Gamma(2n+2)}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{z}}\,\text{arctanh}\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-z}}{2}}\tag{D}$$
and finally to
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arctan\left(\frac{2}{\cos^2\theta}\right)\,d\theta = \pi\arctan\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}}.$$
As a corollary, $z=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is a special value for the hypergeometric function ${}_2 F_1\left(\tfrac{3}{4},\tfrac{3}{4};\tfrac{7}{4};z\right)$.
This can be done also by differentiation under the integral sign, since $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\arctan\left(\frac{a}{\cos^2\theta}\right)\,d\theta$ is not that difficult to compute.